# Another twist on Type Providers

Tags: f#, runtime, compile-time, type-providers

Trying to extend the boundary of the usage of type provider, I figured I could use :

```
//Does not work
let exceldatatype = MyExcelTypeProvider.ExcelFile<filename="Brokernet.xls">
let file = new exceldatatype()
let f1(elem:exceldatatype .Row) = 
    elem.BID
```

this works though :

```
//Works
let file= MyExcelTypeProvider.ExcelFile<filename="Brokernet.xls">()
let f1(elem:MyExcelTypeProvider.ExcelFile<filename="Brokernet.xls">.Row) = 
    elem.BID
```

This does not work either :

```
//Does not work
let typealias = MyExcelTypeProvider.ExcelFile<filename="Brokernet.xls">.Row
```

I guess there is some deep lesson to be found there about runtime and compile time properties, but I am not sure what.

**UPDATE**

As specified by the ever helpful kvb, the following works :

```
type typealias = MyExcelTypeProvider.ExcelFile<filename="Brokernet.xls">
let file2 = new typealias()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line, try `type ... = ...` instead of `let ... = ...`.